# Could not find class when running puppet apply with modulepath

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Running puppet apply with the modulepath switch fails with `Error: Could not find class apt for vagrant.example.com on node vagrant.example.com`

Puppet version is 3.7.3 running on Ubuntu 14.04 managed by Vagrant and VirtualBox

This is the command I'm running:

`sudo puppet apply --debug --verbose --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0'  /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp`

The output

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo puppet apply --debug --verbose --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0'  /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp
Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in `issue_deprecation_warning')
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.7.3, ruby_version=1.9.3, run_mode=user, default_encoding=US-ASCII
Info: Loading facts
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_update_last_success.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_updates.rb
Info: Loading facts
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-concat/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
Info: Loading facts
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Debug: Loading facts from /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Error: Could not find class apt for vagrant.example.com on node vagrant.example.com
Error: Could not find class apt for vagrant.example.com on node vagrant.example.com
```

The content of /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp`

```
node default 
{ 
  include apt
}
```

The content of /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root vagrant  714 Jan  5 20:03 puppetlabs-apt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root vagrant  680 Jan  5 20:03 puppetlabs-concat
drwxr-xr-x 1 root vagrant  782 Jan  5 20:03 puppetlabs-postgresql
drwxr-xr-x 1 root vagrant  782 Jan  5 20:03 puppetlabs-stdlib
```

Running `puppet module list` with same modulepath does indeed list the modules (including puppetlabs-apt which I'm refering to), albeit with dependencies warnings.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ puppet module list --debug --verbose --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0'
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-apt':
  'puppetlabs-postgresql' (v4.1.0) requires 'puppetlabs-apt' (>=1.1.0 <2.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-concat':
  'puppetlabs-postgresql' (v4.1.0) requires 'puppetlabs-concat' (>= 1.1.0 <2.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-stdlib':
  'puppetlabs-apt' (v1.7.0) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (>= 2.2.1)
  'puppetlabs-concat' (v1.1.2) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (>= 3.2.0 < 5.0.0)
  'puppetlabs-postgresql' (v4.1.0) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (v4.x)
/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0
├── puppetlabs-apt (v1.7.0)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.1.2)
├── puppetlabs-postgresql (v4.1.0)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.5.0)
```

The strange thing is that `puppet module list` seems to be finding the modules, but referring to any of the modules in my manifest file fails (same class error if I try to include postgresql). I have a feeling that my manifest file is wrong. Am I missing something obvious here?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename the module folder `puppetlabs-apt` to `apt`

or change the pp code

from

```
include apt
```

to

```
include puppetlabs-apt
```

Depend on how you defined in apt pp file.

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I'm using librarian-puppet, and the way I had declared the module dependency caused the folder to be named puppetlabs-apt instead of just apt.